# Haskell: How to combine scalar and monadic values?

Tags: arrays, haskell, state-monad

Currently I'm fiddling around with a haskell problem concerning an 2D ST Array and recursion.

Given a 2D position and an array of directions, I wrote a line returning a list of all resulting points inside the array:

```
let cellsAround = [resPt | dir <- directions,
                         let resPt = (fst dir + fst point, snd dir + snd point),
                         fst resPt >= 0 && fst resPt <= fst maxIdx &&
                         snd resPt >= 0 && snd resPt <= snd maxIdx]
```

Now the goal is to enrich the resulting list items with the contents of the array and I tried this one:

```
cellsAround <- sequence [readArray board resPt | dir <- directions,
                         let resPt = (fst dir + fst point, snd dir + snd point),
                         fst resPt >= 0 && fst resPt <= fst maxIdx &&
                         snd resPt >= 0 && snd resPt <= snd maxIdx]
```

This also works great. But the goal is to get a combination of both [(Point, Int)] because I have to filter on the array content.

Any ideas how to combine this to, say

```
(resPt, readArray board resPt)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal change:

```
sequence [(,) resPt <$> readArray board resPt
         | ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't find this (,) via Hoogle :-(

Comment: @Hennes `(,)` is the pair constructor, and `(,) a` is a short way to write `(\b -> (a,b))`.

Comment: to be honest with you, I'll prefer using `-XTupleSections` here, namely `sequence [(resPt,) <$> readArray board resPt ...` which is much more convenient and readable than the original answer.